# Not getting 100 rep for associating accounts

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I didn't get my 100 starting reputation from associating this account to my other accounts.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127/i-didnt-get-my-100-starting-reputation-from-associating-this-account-to-my-other)

I, and atleast one other (JCL), didn't get the +100 reputation for associating other stackexchange accounts. [This thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/923/i-didnt-get-my-100-starting-reputation-from-associating-this-account-to-my-other/926#926) in the main forum was created about it, because we weren't able to ask this question on meta in the first place.

**EDIT**
I fixed my problem by unlinking and relinking the accounts, like people were advising.

Answer (score 1):

This is SE-wide bug; if you need this +100 now, create account on any other SE site, this should make the transfer here. Yet this will be fixed, hopefully soon.

Related meta question: [Account association not giving +100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70147/account-association-not-giving-100/70149#70149)

Comment: I can't find a thread either. Is this is a well-known problem? Or do the powers-that-be not know about it yet?

Comment: I know about it since it was mentioned in moderators' [secret secret secret]; meta suggests it is fixed, so I think you should add an answer there that it is still a problem.