# I didn't get my 100 starting reputation from associating this account to my other accounts.

Tags: status-completed

Thus, I can't ask this question in meta, since it takes at least 5 reputation. Can a mod transfer this?

Comment: why worry about reputation as long as you can ask questions and answer them?

Comment: I can't upvote answers or questions. I can't comment on other people's answers or questions either. I don't have any question in particular to ask, the ways in which I can participate are seriously limited.

Comment: Humm when you say right to vote... I think you have got a point :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not getting 100 rep for associating accounts](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122/not-getting-100-rep-for-associating-accounts)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by unlinking and then linking my profile a second time.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, so I can't put this as a comment on this question. Regardless of if I need the reputation, it's a bug, so I just wanted to mention I experienced it too.

**EDIT** - I've got 6 rep now, so I cross-posted a question in [meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122/not-getting-100-rep-for-associating-accounts) that links here.

**EDIT** - xbones: I've got accounts at SO,SU,SF,Ubuntu,Gaming,DIY and others. For each of them, I've always gotten the +100 at the new site I'm using, not the site I'm linking to. If this has changed, then it's changed, but I hadn't heard anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

When I made an account here, I got 100 rep at Stack Overflow, not here. You get the 'linking' rep at the other stack exchange website you're a part of.

EDIT: I just happened to visit Physics.stackexchange again and this time, I got a notification that I got +100 for linking.